# bash script output not updating

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm reading my machines cpu load however the results aren't updating and the first result is constantly displayed.

```
#!/bin/bash
LOAD=$(ps aux|awk 'NR > 0 { s +=$3 }; END {print s"%"}')
(while true; do
echo "$LOAD"
sleep 1
done)
```

this returns

```
0.3%
0.3%
0.3%
0.3%
0.3%
```

even though the load has changed during this time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calculating the `LOAD` value just once and then printing forever that value. Instead, you have to calculate the value inside the `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
   LOAD=$(ps aux|awk 'NR > 0 { s +=$3 }; END {print s"%"}')
   echo "$LOAD"
   sleep 1
done
```

#### Test

```
$ ./a
81.2%
81.2%
81.1%
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the variable `LOAD` is evaluated just once.

You could convert it into a function instead:

```
LOAD() { ps aux|awk 'NR > 0 { s +=$3 }; END {print s"%"}'; }
while true; do
  LOAD
  sleep 1
done
```